# "System" could not be resolved even though imports are correct

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, java.lang.class

When I compile my JSP page, it does not seem to work since it doesn't resolve the `System` class. I need to get the time in milliseconds so I can input it in the DB

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [63] in the jsp file: [/VerifyBid.jsp]
System cannot be resolved

60:                 + "VALUES(?,?)"; // this is just a segment of the SQL Query
61:                 ps = con.prepareStatement(insert);
62:                 ps.setString(1, bid);
63:                 ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
64:                 ps.executeUpdate();
65:
```

Here are my imports:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter,java.lang.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.dbapp.*" %>
```

I tried going into my project properties and making sure I had the most up to date JRE. I also made sure my imports were correct, which they appear to be. This is the only time I use the System class anywhere in my program so it is the only file that seems to be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was that the version of Apache Tomcat I was using was having trouble with the JRE. I solved this by using the latest version of Apache, which would happen to be version 10 at the time of this writing.